# Пакетное выполнение команд в Windows

Tags: windows

Я пишу программу, которая при каждом запуске требует, чтобы я выполнял несколько функций подряд.

1. Останавливал сервер из коммандной строки (Ctrl+c)
2. Обновлял страницу в Internet Explorer(e) и т.д.

Есть ли такая программа, которая могла бы записать эти несколько действий и потом делала бы их сама, по моей комманде?

Comment: Возьмите [AutoIT](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно из любой удобной программы создавать на лету такой скрипт - по сути макрос (cmd, js, vbs, ps1), который позволяет выполнять необходимые действия, а затем временно передавать управление скрипту.

В сети встречаются готовые программы, которые записывают макросы (Macro Recorder и подобные).

Если речь идет о тестировании, полезно взглянуть на Microsoft UI Automation.

Comment: Мне кажется, Macro Recorder то, что надо.